# calculating variable discounts using a dropdownlist in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, operators

Hi ive got a drop down list where a qty of items can be selected. 1-8. 
For each item as an example if they buy one they get 25% off. if they buy 2 they get 30% 3 35%, (so it goes up 5% each time they purchase an item.

What would be an easier way to do this? mine seems quite tedious. Can you provide an exaple code please.

This is what i have but i would have to do many if statements.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        int test = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(test * (199 * (1 - 0.25)));
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        int test = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(test * (199 * (1 - 0.30)));
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "3")
    {
        int test = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(test * (199 * (1 - 0.35)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work on Selected Index. Because it gives a number.

Multiply that number with `0.05 (0.35 -0.30 = 0.05, 0.30-0.25 = 0.05)` and add in `0.25`

Let's say `Selected Index` is `0` then `(0 * 0.05) + 0.25 = 0.25`

If its `1` then `(1 * 0.05) + 0.25 = 0.30`

and so on....

Answer (score 1):

try this but make sure to chek that the value selected is not 0

```
int test = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
if(test!=0)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(test * (199 * (1 - (0.25+(5*(test-1))))))
}
```